# Flex: Combobox creating dropdown with less values

Tags: apache-flex, drop-down-menu, combobox, flex3

I have an object that inherits from combobox.  This is done so I can use a custom framework for creation and value setting and uses a 'id' / 'description' set for the dataprovider.  When I set the value, i set the 'id' and the custom object looks through the dataprovider to find the matching id to find the index.  When setting the value, I don't know the 'dscription', that is what the row source is for.

My problem is in that I need to display 'old' values when I first set the value through code, but I don't want to allow the user to see the 'old' value in the dropdown and allow them to select it.

Now, I've been trying to chase down the best way to do this.  I'm assuming I need to either interrupt the creation of the dropdown dataprovider and populate it with a smaller list(using my own 'hideFromDropdown' property) or find out if there is a way to add a property to my dataprovider that causes the item to not be rendered by the dropdown.  Perhaps eich 'item' in the dropdown has a visible property?

I was able to trace down to the combobox.getDropdown method, which creates a new dropdown from the dropdownfacrory.  Unfortunatly, this is private so I can't override it to pass a partial rowsource.  Now, all the dropdownfacory seems to do is return a basic list.  Unfortunately I keep getting lost tracking down to find the place in the list or listbase objects where the individual item in the dataprovider gets rendered(or not).  I believe I have traced to listContent:ListBaseContentHolder in ListBase which contains the data, but am constantly getting lost in the ambiguities.

I am using Flex SDK 3.6A in Adobe Flex Builder 3(built on the Eclipse engine)

Comment: You need a subset of the dataProvider based on some criteria?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I can't seem to override and change how the dataprovider for the dropdown is copied from the combobox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [filterfunction](http://kirill-poletaev.blogspot.com/2011/07/arraycollection-in-flex-part-4.html) on the dataProvider like arrayList/arraycollection. Checkout the example here

http://kirill-poletaev.blogspot.com/2011/07/arraycollection-in-flex-part-4.html

Comment: I didn't know you can do that to an arraycollection, but how do I access the dataProvider for the dropdown or separate the dataProvider for the dropdown from the one for the combobox so I don't filter the combobox?

Comment: You may have to duplicate into another arraycollection and work on it if you need two copies.

Comment: Or does this make it so I can filter the display, but if I set the index to an item that is 'filtered' it will still be displayed on the combobox?

Comment: But if I duplicate the dataProvider and work on it(filter it down) how do I assign it to the dropdown as the combobox getdropdown method automatically assigns the combobox dataProvider to the new dropdown instance it returns?

Comment: This may be a workaround: First when the page is loaded, do not filter the list. when the user tries to open the combobox(handle show/some event on the list) and filter the list just before it is drawn on the screen.

Comment: But how do I get access to the dropdown instance?  It is created inside the combobox privately stored.

Comment: You can catch the 'open' event on the combobox. Try to catch it on 'capture' phase. Obviously you try to setDataProvider on the combobox, you dont need to have the list instance in that case.

Comment: OK, so you are saying override the Open method, and change the dataProvider before calling the super.open that creates the dropdown, then override the close method that resets the dataprovider after the dropdown is gone.  That should work.  I'll try it.